# Cooking own pizza in a microwave

Tags: pizza, microwave

Can I make my own pizza dough and cook it in the microwave? Is there any chance that I could reach acceptable results?

Comment: Define "acceptable". With the introduction of microwave ovens, one "selling point" was the ability to bake bread without it getting a crust. That would generally be unacceptable for a pizza, but if you're just hungry your mileage may vary.

Comment: @sourd'oh: Acceptable: somethign you would eat despite having other choices, or as your first choice. How can you bake bread in a microwave? You mean from scratch?

Comment: In that case, assuming your other choices include something at least as good as peanut butter and jelly sandwiches, then no, you cannot make a pizza that good in the microwave.

Answer (score 1):

Pure microwave: **no way**
Microwave with combo/grill functions: **maybe**.

I bake cakes in a combo microwave oven and results are pretty good, using manufacturer suggested pans and specific recipes.